# Simple way to sample from a Gaussian distribution on SO(3) rotation group

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, differential-geometry, probability-distributions, rotations

Given a mean and variance, I want to be able to sample rotations that are "normally distributed" according to this mean and variance. I have a metric over rotations, the chordal metric: $\| R_1 - R_2\|$ which tells us how close two rotations are to each other. How do I do this?

One way is to consider SO(3) as a sphere $S^3$ in $R^4$, the space of quaternions, but I don't know how to setup the Gaussian distribution correctly in this case considering a single rotation in SO(3) is an antipodal pair in $S^3$.

Comment: How are you defining a Gaussian distribution on $SO(3)$? It seems there are several inequivalent ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking, there is something called Bingham distribution, which can be used to sample quaternions from the $S^3$  sphere (or even other dimensional spheres). It even coveres the problem of quaternions being antipodal since the distribution is nicely symetric.

[Link to wiki here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingham_distribution) (although it isn't very thorough)

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.03957.pdf) is where I stumbled on it for the fist time. The article is focused on Reinforcement learning but they do also give a pretty good explanation of what the distribution is about.

I would suggest finding some library, that can do this tho, since making it from scratch seems to me like madness.